# Products of the oxidation of 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: Oxidation of 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane]

I am having difficulty identifying the second product. Is it an ether, or a kind of epoxide? I am out of ideas on how to reach it.

However, I do have a general idea how to receive the first product, in the means of knowing that I have to first turn the 1,4-dimethylcyclohexane to an alkyl halide and then into an alkene and then an epoxide.

I would be grateful to receive an idea of how to start.

Comment: It's an ether, obviously.

Comment: I would imagine you can access it via 1,4-dimethylcyclohea-1,4-diene

Comment: would it be logical that after reaching 1,4-dimethylcyclohea-1,4-diene doing the following:
1.hydration (to add OH next to Me)
2.hydrohalogenation( to add Br next to the opposite Me)
3.NaOH, H2O(to reduce OH to O-, thus allowing an intramolecular Sn2 reaction to occur).
open to corrections.